# Format JSON Datetime on client side by Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a date to string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933320/convert-a-date-to-string-in-javascript)

I have date in json format at client side :

```
/Date(1352745000000)/
```

The code which i have tried to parse Json date:

```
eval(dateTime.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
```

and

```
new Date(parseInt(dateTime.substr(6)));
```

Out put I am getting:

```
Tue Nov 27 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**Desire Output**

```
 2012-11-27 11:16
```

I am not able to figure out how we will get this.

Comment: That `eval` is completely unnecessary, and is incorrect besides.

Comment: @Asad: It's working fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(dateTime.substr(6)));
var formatted = date.getFullYear() + "-" + 
      ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + 
      ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + 
      date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Wrong, getMonth() does not work that way - it gives zero-based number of the month.

Comment: Also you need to pad the hours and minutes as well

Answer (score 5):

Best not to try save space with this one :)

```
var str, year, month, day, hour, minute, d, finalDate;

str = "/Date(1352745000000)/".replace(/\D/g, "");
d = new Date( parseInt( str ) );

year = d.getFullYear();
month = pad( d.getMonth() + 1 );
day = pad( d.getDate() );
hour = pad( d.getHours() );
minutes = pad( d.getMinutes() );

finalDate =  year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes;

function pad( num ) {
    num = "0" + num;
    return num.slice( -2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is not string - you are getting string representation of [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You need to format it in proper way before further processing. To see how to do that, just see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398929/548696

To add time to the date, see documentation on Date JS object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date