# Date format in jquery using ajax data array

Tags: jquery, ajax, date

How can I get simple date format from following code:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/ZMWebService/ZMServiceUserRole.asmx/GetUserRoleList",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "RoleName" },
                    { "data": "Description" },
                    { "data": "CreatedBy" },
                    { "data": "CreateDate" },
                    { "data": "ModifiedBy" },
                    { "data": "ModifyDate" },
```

it is displaying date as follow:

```
Date(1422729000000)
```

How can I get simple date format from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549922/format-json-datetime-on-client-side-by-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: You can use the jquery plugin dateFormating and try it at: http://jsfiddle.net/adamculpepper/rHXcp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var date = "/Date(1422729000000)/".substr(6);
    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(date ));
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
   alert(date);
```

Comment: Worth a note about getMonth's return value which is 0-based - therefore the `+1`. Always a good opportunity to shot yourself in the foot. :]