# how to add minutes to datetime string in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

i am getting in Json  format the follow

```
09\/14\/2013 14:00
```

i would like to add minutes to the date and display the value as string
should i convert it to datetime, add and convert back? if yes then how?

Comment: you mean add minutes as in manipulation of time (say current time + 60 minutes)?

Comment: May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object

Comment: Is this helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933320/convert-a-date-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: best way is to use `new Date()` it will create the current time. Then just wait however many minutes you need, then call it again. That should work

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```js
var dat = new Date('09/14/2013 14:00'); // Change the string to Date
console.log(dat);
console.log(dat.getMinutes()); // Get the minutes of your dateTime
dat.setMinutes('23'); // Set the minutes you wish
console.log(dat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have converted this to a `Date()` object in Javascript, you can use the `getMinutes()` function to obtain the minutes in the date, perform your logic to add minutes, and then set the minutes using the `setMinutes()` function.