# How do I convert to DateTime when the time is a decimal?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a data table, from Sage 100 ERP to be specific, that uses two separate columns to store the updated date and time (DateUpdated and TimeUpdated). I need to convert the data in these two fields to a DateTime object for comparisons. The dates look like "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00 AM" and the time is a decimal like 14.29297. So far I have been able to convert the time to the minute as follows:

```
private DateTime GetDateTime(string date, decimal time)
    {
        int hour = int.Parse(Math.Floor(time).ToString());
        decimal minTemp = decimal.Parse((60 * (time - hour)).ToString());
        int min = int.Parse(Math.Round(minTemp).ToString());
        int sec = int.Parse(Math.Round(60 * (minTemp - min)).ToString());

        string datetime = date + " " + hour.ToString() + ":" + min.ToString();

        return DateTime.Parse(datetime);
    }
```

I remove the 12:00AM from the date string before I pass it to this method. This works, but I'm loosing the seconds which is very important.

How can I convert the time to hours, minutes, and seconds?

Comment: Might want to refer to the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933320/convert-a-date-to-string-in-javascript

Comment: Can you provide a sample for time too?

Comment: What exactly does the decimal value represent?

Comment: I also see that you have not appended sec to datetime string.

Comment: The time is like 14.29297

Comment: The decimal is the hours, so for example, 2.5 would be 2:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could avoid all that extra processing and just do this:

```
DateTime GetDateTime(string date, decimal time)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(datetime).AddHours((double)time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cory, this is what I ended up doing based on Matt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just parse what you have:

```
private DateTime GetDateTime(string date, decimal time)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulutre);

    double hours = Convert.ToDouble(time);

    return dt.AddHours(hours);
}
```

Of course, it would be a lot easier if you had the correct data types to begin with.  I have a feeling somewhere you have a `DateTime` and a `double` anyway (perhaps when you read the data from the database), and you are improperly converting them to `string` and `decimal`.

Comment: Also, I was getting an exception with ParseExact, so I am just doing DateTime.Parse(date). It is giving me the correct DateTime values.

Comment: If you were getting an exception, then you probably have data that doesn't match the format supplied.  Now you are probably hiding the problem.  Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not a `typo` - you are missing to append `seconds` value to the `datetime` string.

Replace This:

```
string datetime = date + " " + hour.ToString() + ":" + min.ToString();
```

With this:

```
string datetime = date + " " + hour.ToString() + ":" + min.ToString()+ ":" + sec.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't believe the seconds calculation is correct. It always comes out to -1.

Comment: @user2842689: could you please provide us the sample decimal time value?

Comment: The time is like 14.29297

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your calculations are correct, did you try appending the second component to the datetime variable as follows:

> string datetime = date + " " + hour.ToString() + ":" + min.ToString()
>   + ":" + sec.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

For the seconds try something like this:

```
int secTemp = int.Parse((Math.Round(60 * (minTemp - min))).ToString());
int sec = (secTemp<0?60 + secTemp:secTemp);
string datetime = date + " " + hour.ToString() + ":" + min.ToString()+ ":" + sec.ToString();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Covert Decimal to Hour and Minute for single Database field

```
        double convertData = 1.75
        TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(convertData);
        string outputH = timespan.ToString("hh");
        string outputM = timespan.ToString("mm");
```

Output will be 1 hour /  45 min